# Pass the bot configuration file so that it is accessible globally from Client

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm wanting to pass my bot's configuration file (`config.json`) into the bot client so I can get for example, the bot's owner ID instead of specifying it in each command that I want only the bot owner to access, or the embed footer text, example:

```
    async execute(client, message, args, footerTxt) {
        if (message.author.id == BotOwnerId) {
```

I want to be able to just have it be

```
       async execute(client, message, args){
                if (message.author.id == client.config.ownerID) {
```

I have tried running it through the command execute

```
    try {
        await client.commands.get(command).execute(client, message, args, footerTxt, config);
    } catch (error) {
```

which resulted in

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ownerID')
at Object.execute
```

Comment: when you initialize the bot, do you assign the config to the client?

Comment: @G-Force No, it gets the token, prefix, versions etc through a lengthy require, and other commands that need something from it also end up with their own require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.json

```
{
   "ownerID": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
   "someOtherStuff": [],
   "someMoreStuff": { "id": 1, "name": "Test" }
}
```

index (assuming config.json is in the same folder)

```
const config = require('./config.json')

await client.commands.get(command).execute(client, message, args, footerTxt, config);
```

cmd:

```
if (message.author.id == config.ownerID) {
```

Why not simply requiring the config file in index and passing it through the args to the command? Or require it in the commands?
As you wish but it should do the trick